# MkMapView was unable to load in xcode 7.0 beta version

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I am trying to create application with `MKMapView`. I drag and drop `MKMapView` in my viewcontroller, and created IBOutlet for that MapView. But, when am running it I am getting the warning as below.

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/VectorKit_Sim/VectorKit-1134.11/GeoCSS/GeoCSS/StyleSheet.cpp:122 STYL Parse: Decode error here
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Did you find any solution. Me also having the same issue please let me know

Comment: Am not getting the above mentioned error in next version